# Does ShellExecute have memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, shellexecute

I'm learning C++. When I call `_run_file("otherapp.exe","")`, current app's memory raise up 1MB. Is any memory leak here? If have, how to fix it? Thank you very much!

```
void _run_file(LPSTR file, LPSTR params)
{
    ShellExecute(NULL,NULL,file,params,NULL,NULL);
}
```

Comment: Really? You suspect the WinAPI of having such a blatant memory leak? Here's an easy test: call _run_file multiple times and see if the memory rises every time. Otherwise, it's probably just delay-loading some DLLs on the first call.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Fisrt time: 1MB, second: 0.2MB, third: 0.1 MB, after then: 0MB

Comment: @user2310322 Does that answer your question or do you still have a question?